# Rspec with multi button form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec

I am building a simple blog in rails and have a form with multiple buttons. One button allows someone to save a draft, and another allows someone to publish a post.

One button has a name for saving the draft, and another has a name to publish the post. If the publish param is present, it will execute the publish function in the post model.

In the controller I have

```
post.publish unless !params[:publish]
```

How do I use rspec to test that if the publish param is present that it will call the publish action on the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it depends. If you do integration testing using capybara, you just say which button shall be clicked. But I guess, you have a controller. So instead of

```
post :create, :post => {...}
```

you need to do

```
post :create, :post => {...}, :publish => "Publish"
```

In reality, the value (label) of the button will be submitted as the value of `params[:publish]`, so you might want to pass the real label of that button as `:publish`.